# How can i Parametrize Azure Json file?

Tags: azure, json, arm

Please see that we have configured Dashboard in our other Azure subscription from where we have downloaded its template.

Now we want to make it IaC (Infrastructure as Code) in our new Azure subscription.

***We also need to parametrize the ARM templates so that it can be linked with any of the environments. [JSON LINK FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h7d1S40plFYrc3oHHAcgwWkWe8akCa-d/view)***

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the JSON representation of the dashboard, the next step is to create a template from this JSON. And then use that template programmatically with the appropriate resource management APIs, command-line tools, or within the portal.

This article walks you through the process of programmatically creating and publishing Azure dashboards:

[Programmatically create Azure Dashboards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically#fetch-the-json-representation-of-the-dashboard)

Hope this helps.